# Pasar una variable javascript a una php o obtener valor de input para almacenar en variable php

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy en el desarrollo d un proyecto, es una agenda electrónica y estoy utilizando FullCalendar y hay una función es javascript que hace que cuando se le de clic a un día este reciba en un  la fecha con el siguiente formato AA-MM-DD, tengo un select que se llena con una consulta SQL y necesito esa fecha ya sea agarrándola del script para pasarla a una variable php o agarrar el valor del  con php para almacenar el valor en una variable y usarla en mi consulta.

**Código javascript**

```
dayClick:function(date,jsEvent,view){
            $('#btnAgregar').prop("disabled",false);
            limpiarFormulario();
            $('#txtFecha').val(date.format());
            $("#ModalEventos").modal();
            
        },
```

En este código manda la fecha del día seleccionado en: $('#txtFecha').val(date.format()); y lo almacena en el input ya mencionado.

```
        <input type="text" id="txtFecha" name="txtFecha" />
```

**Código php**

```
     <?php
     $var = $_POST['dato'];       
     $sql4="SELECT CAST(start AS TIME) FROM eventos2 WHERE CAST(start AS DATE)='AQUI ES DONDE QUIERO PONER LA VARIABLE QUE TENGA LA FECHA'";
     $sql_resultado4 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql4);
     while( $fila4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $sql_resultado4 )){
     $nuevo_array4[] = $fila4;
     }
     ?>
```

En este código esta mi consulta donde quiero poner la variable o lo que se pueda hacer que tenga esa fecha en el where.

Espero que me puedan ayudar :(

**CABE ACLARAR QUE LOS CÓDIGOS SE ENCUENTRAN EN UNA MISMA PÁGINA PHP LA CUAL ES "Servicio_social.php"**

Comment: en tu variable "var" de PHP quieres guardar el valor que esta en tu input txtFecha?

Comment: Solo recuerda que PHP se ejecuta del lado del servidor y JS del lado del cliente, entonces para que la información llegue al servidor o bien usas AJAX o un formulario para enviar la información. Yo en tu caso usaría AJAX para que no sea necesario recargar la página. Saludos.

Comment: concuerdo con @Josue, que uses ajax pero veo q estas recien partiendo, yo veo que quieres que vaya al PHP como formulario. Entonces debes ya tener un input submit que envie todo los campos que esten dentro del <form> incluido el campo "txtFecha". En PHP debes buscarlo igual a como lo tienes en tu $var = $_POST['dato'];  pero con el name que le asignaste: $var2 = $_POST['txtFecha']; . ya ahi lo tienes en tu $var2 y lo trabajas en PHP

Comment: Exacto Javier, eso es lo que quiero, se me olvido quitar esa parte del código pero si, es lo que quiero.

JosueArriola y Rodrihgo, me podrían dar un ejemplo, desconozco de ajax.

Comment: @Javierfr, si, es lo que quiero

Comment: @JosueArriola, me podrías dar un ejemplo. Ya estuve intentando pero nada.

Comment: @Rodrihgo, me podrías dar un ejemplo. Ya estuve intentando pero nada.

Answer (score 1):

> Preparamos datos

```js
$("#id_button").click(function(){
  //en la variable fecha guardo el valor que tiene el input
  var fecha = document.getElementById("txtFecha");

  $.ajax({
      url : "rutadelafucionquerecibiralafecha.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {fecha: fecha}
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data) {
        //si todo sale bien mando mensaje
        alert("muy bien");
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("algo salio mal");
          conole.log(errorThrown);
      }
  });
          
});
```

> Recibimos datos en archivo y función que se indico en el Ajax

```
<?php 
  try {
    //guadamos la fecha en una variable de PHP
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha']; 
    //aqui ya haces tu proceso de enviar la variable a tu consuta mysql
    $nombreConexion = mysqli_connect($hostname , $nombreUsuario , $contraseña);
    $result = mysqli_query($nombreConexion, "Consulta aquí");

    if($result) {
      echo json_encode(array("status" => true));
    }
  } catch (Exception $e) {
      show_error($e->getMessage() . ' --- ' . $e->getTraceAsString());
  } //./catch

?>
```

Comment: Hay que indicarle al OP que debe añadir jQuery a su proyecto para poder utilizar AJAX. Saludos.